# Eigenvalues of $I-A^{t}A$ where $A$ is a semi orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

A friend asked me the following:

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over a field $\mathbb{F}$ s.t
>   $AA^{t}=I_{m}$. Prove $I_{n}-A^{t}A$ is not invertible.

**My** **thoughts**:

If $m=n$ then $A$ is unitary and $AA^{t}=A^{t}A=I_{n}$ and the
claim follows.

By similar arguments of the above case I have deduced that the rows
of $A$ are a orthonormal set.

It seems that the diagonal entries of $B=AA^{t}$ are $1$. I hoped
that $B$ being symmetric and diagonal of $1$ means that $1$ is
an eigenvalue of $B$ but this is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $A(Id-A^tA)=0$. Thus, $(Id-A^tA)$ can not be invertible, because $A\neq 0$.